# How to add an interface programmatically on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

How to add any interface programmatically on Linux?

Is there any way, to add eth, loop or tun interface? 
Can it be done via netlink?

Language is C++, OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you asking how to do something in C++ that you know how to do from shell commands?  If so: can you list the shell commands you'd like to mimic?  And then...what constraint is keeping you from calling out to the shell? (or: what's painted you into the corner of using C++ in the first place?)

Comment: Well what kind of linux we r talking about... Mandriva , ubuntu , Debian .
It will make easy for u to add a interface for program i like to use Eclipse or add on ur PC the wine and instal teh visual studio 2010

Comment: @HostileFork I don't know how to do it from shell commands too

Answer (score 7):

The way to add an interface depends on the kind of interface. A [tun or tap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) interface for example is created by opening `/dev/net/tun` and setting a few `ioctl`s on the file descriptor you obtain. Here's a minimal example from the [Linux kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt):

```
  #include <linux/if.h>
  #include <linux/if_tun.h>

  int tun_alloc(char *dev)
  {
      struct ifreq ifr;
      int fd, err;

      if( (fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0 )
         return tun_alloc_old(dev);

      memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

      /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers) 
       *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device  
       *
       *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information  
       */ 
      ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN; 
      if( *dev )
         strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

      if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0 ){
         close(fd);
         return err;
      }
      strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
      return fd;
  }
```